# What is the Kuroda method for transmission lines and why is it usefull?

Tags: filter, transmission-line

I recentrly heard about the Kuroda method (when speaking about transmission lines) but didn't understand what it really is and why it might be usefull.

Could someone give a brief explanation?
why would you use that technique to e.g. make filters? What s the main specificity about that technique in comparison to others?

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: *Could someone give a brief explanation?* Not unless you specify what you already know about transmission lines. You'll realize we can't start explaining an advanced microwave technique in an answer if we have to start with Ohm's law.

Comment: You need to be more specific in asking a question. What is it you don't understand?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I can make amost of the filters in microstrip technology and use various tools for simulation and tuning. In other words I know the basics (inter alia Ohm s law) I guess

Comment: @bud why would you use that technique to e.g. make filters? What s the main specificity about that technique in comparison to others?

Answer (score 2):

As frequency increases the parasitic of the lump components become significant. That is why we need distributed filters. The Kuroda transform is a way to implement any capacitor or inductor value using only transmission lines. By using transmission lines only you avoid the capacitor and inductor parasitics. See [this](http://whites.sdsmt.edu/classes/ee481/notes/481Lecture31.pdf) for more information.

Comment: I have been perplexed by this subject for some time. The link you cited made me realize that the textbook I've been using that discusses Kuroda's identities has a serious mistake in it.

Answer (score 1):

The Kuroda identities are used to transform between series and shunt (stub) transmission line elements. This is useful because in certain types of transmission line structures (i.e. microstrip) series transmission line structures are not realizable. One of the primary uses of the Kuroda identities is in basic microstrip filter design. Other uses include series to stub transformations for impedance matching purposes. See the following books for more information:

Microwave Engineering 4th Edition, D.M. Pozar
http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002016.html

Planar Microwave Engineering, T. Lee
http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/engineering/rf-and-microwave-engineering/planar-microwave-engineering-practical-guide-theory-measurement-and-circuits